# Stopped Brownian motion proof

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to work through a proof in [Durrett's textbook](https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) of a martingale convergence theorem via an embedding of the martingale in Brownian motion, and am stuck verifying a detail as usual.

I'm looking at Theorem 8.8.2 in the above link (I'll leave out re-writing everything so it doesn't get cluttered). I can't seem to figure out the step where he conditions on the $\sigma$-field at time $T_{m-1}$ (top of p. 431):

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E(t_m; M \geq m) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E[E(t_M \mid \mathcal{B}_{T_{m-1}}); M \geq m] $$

I understand that $\{M \geq m\} \in \mathcal{F}_{m-1}$ so by conditioning each term of the sum on that set you are left with something involving the last term (Durrett's claim: $E(t_M \mid \mathcal{B}_{T_{m-1}})$), but my question is: why is it $t_M$ and not $T_M$?

In the LHS of the above, it looks like if you expand out the sum and cancel terms, then one ought to be left with $T_M-T_0$, where $T_0 = 0$ so you're just left with $T_M$ rather than $t_M = T_M - T_{M-1}$. I've gotta be missing something obvious here...

Comment: If you understand that each of the terms leaves you with $\mathbb{E}(t_M \mid \mathcal{B}_{T_{m-1}})$, then where is the problem? That's exactly what he claims, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant (see last paragraph). I'll edit.

Comment: (Sorry, for the confusion.) The equality $\sum_{k=1}^M t_m = T_M$ holds only for $\omega \in \{M<\infty\}$; otherwise the right-hand side is not well-defined, right?

Comment: @saz: I don't quite follow what equation you're referring to. I see where Durrett works with this later in the proof but I'm not sure how this relates to the identity in my post. Sorry if I'm just being slow.

Comment: In the linked file, it reads $$ \mathbb{E} \sum_{m=1}^M t_m = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E(t_m; M \geq m) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E[E(t_M \mid \mathcal{B}_{T_{m-1}}); M \geq m] $$ and I thought that you wanted to know why the left-hand side does not simply equal $\mathbb{E}T_M$. If this is not your question, then, again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @saz: No, you're right. Thanks for that. I see your comment, but I guess I'm just asking about simple arithmetic where he substitutes the last difference $t_M$ rather than just $T_M$, in: $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E(t_m; M \geq m)$ to $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} E(E(t_M | \mathcal{B}(T_{m-1} )); M \geq m)$.